# Результаты работы foreach в одну переменную

Tags: php

Есть массив:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Выводиться foreach. Как сделать так, чтобы вся работа foreach записывалась в одну переменую, к примеру, чтобы переменная `$foo` получилась такого значения:

```
$foo= "<p>1</p><p>2</p><p>3</p><p>4</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $foo .= '<p>' . $value . '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$foo = '<p>' . join('</p><p>', $arr) . '</p>';
```